# Wave prediction after a FFT with a certain phase and frequency

Tags: r, signal-processing, fft, prediction

I am using a sliding window to extract information from my EEG data with a FFT. Now I want to predict the signal from my window into the next one. So I extract the phase from a 0.25 second time window to predict for the next 0.25 second long window.

I am new to signal-processing/prediction, so my knowledge here is a little rusty.

I am not able to generate a sine wave with my extracted phase and frequency. I am just not finding a solution. I might just need a push into the right direction, who knows.

Is there a function in R to help me generate a suitable sine wave?

So I have my maximum Frequency with the phase extracted and need to generate a wave with this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is pseudo-code to synthesize a sin curve of chosen frequency ... currently it assumes an initial seed phase shift of zero so just alter the theta value if you need a different initial phase shift

```
func pop_audio_buffer(number_of_samples float64, given_freq float64,
    samples_per_second float64) ([]float64, error) {

    // output sinusoidal curve is assured to both start and stop at the zero cross over threshold,
    // independent of supplied input parms which control samples per cycle and buffer size.
    // This avoids that "pop" which otherwise happens when rendering audio curves
    // which begins at say 0.5 of a possible range -1 to 0 to +1


    int_number_of_samples := int(number_of_samples)

    if int_number_of_samples == 0 {

        panic("ERROR - seeing 0 number_of_samples in pop_audio_buffer ... float number_of_samples " +
            FloatToString(number_of_samples) + " is your desired_num_seconds too small ? " +
            " or maybe too low value of sample rate")
    }

    source_buffer := make([]float64, int_number_of_samples)

    incr_theta := (2.0 * math.Pi * given_freq) / samples_per_second

    theta := 0.0

    for curr_sample := 0; curr_sample < int_number_of_samples; curr_sample++ {

        source_buffer[curr_sample] = math.Sin(theta)

        theta += incr_theta
    }

    return source_buffer, nil

} //      pop_audio_buffer
```